# high resolution (< 1.24km/pixel) physical map with global coverage?

Tags: geospatial

I find ESRI's World Physical Basemap very good because you can see 1) topography, and 2) habitat. However, the problem is that it isn't very fine resolution (1.24 km/pixel outside the US), so it's only really useful for broader scale maps.
Does anyone know any high-resolution (<1.24km/pixel) physical map with global coverage?

Comment: I don't think that exists.  Global land coverage, perhaps, but global coverage, probably not.

Comment: "Blue Marble" is down to 250m / pixel. Otherwise some of the Natural Earth stuff might be useful, although it shows physical rather than cultural. How fine do you need?

Comment: 250m / pixel might be good enough, and it's certainly better than 1.24km / pixel. I haven't looked at Blue Marble for years - I'll go back and have another look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the EarthEnv project (http://www.earthenv.org/) might have a lot of what you need. While most of the non-elevation data is at the 1km resolution, the reprocessed DEM available there is at a 90m resolution.

Another potential source of data is from government agencies themselves (one such listing of most available government data is here: http://www.opengeocode.org/opendata/). If there is a place in particular that you're looking into, the respective government agencies might have something available.